# Best way to keep a table small by removing old (past date) entries with code first asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to know the best way to remove old entries (with a date from past) from a table that is created using the 'SpaceEvent' entity with EF code first. The objective is to keep the table as small as possible.

**Specifically I want to remove entries that are in the past (ex. anything from yesterday or before)

Do I create a service and run it independently of my website or do I create a program in my website solution that somehow gets started when my website gets published that runs every N minutes, or do I run something from Sql Server? What's the best solution here.

Here is my entity

```
public class SpaceEvent
{
    [Key]
    public int SpaceEventId { get; set; }
    //public string Title { get; set; }
    [Index]
    //research more about clustered indexes to see if it's really needed here
    //[Index(IsClustered = true, IsUnique = false)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateTimeScheduled { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AppointmentLength { get; set; }
    public int StatusEnum { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student.RegisteredStudent> RegisteredStudents { get; set; }
    public int RegisteredStudentCount { get; set; }

    public byte[] LastRegisteredStudentImage { get; set; } // represents the last student to register for the class
    public string LastRegisteredStudentPhrase { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public int SpaceRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SpaceRefId")]
    public virtual Space Space { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you are running on-prem and have SQL Server Agent installed, you could schedule a job with a T-SQL step with the needed purge script.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Hangfire. It's built to specifically handle these types of scenarios. You can simply set up a recurring task and it will run on any interval you request. Best part is, it runs as part of your web application so there's no need to create messy windows services and it deploys easily.

[Hangfire Website](http://hangfire.io)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell you "the best solution". Your question has an opinion-based answer.

However, I think the easiest way is creating and T-SQL script, and run it directly in SQL SERVER. The problem with this solution, is that you need to do this manually. If you want something automatic, you could use a service, like Azure Web Jobs. So, you can create a console-like C# program, and schedule it to run in a specific interval of time.

To see more information about Azure Web Jobs, take a look at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/